# Is it possible to solve/approximate this relation?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, approximation, conditional-probability, divergent-series

I have the following relation:
$$\int_0^\infty 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{n!}g(n)e^{-g(n)x}x\;
\mathrm{d}x= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{n!}g(n)$$

Is it possible to isolate the unknown function $g(n)$, assuming that $g$ is a discrete function?

I tried taking the log of both sides and I couldn't really get anywhere - just a bunch of diverging integrals. I'm guessing there's a good chance that it's not possible to simplify this equation any further, but I'm interested in trying to approximate what $g(n)$ could be. I have no reason to believe $g(n)$ is anything in particular, but I'm not sure how to use that fact.

(One could also re-write the expression:
$$\int_0^\infty 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)g(n)e^{-g(n)x}x\;
\mathrm{d}x= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)g(n)$$
where f is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda$

or even further: 
$$\int_0^\infty 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)B(x)x\;
\mathrm{d}x= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)g(n)$$

where $B(x)$ is Exponentially distributed with parameter $g(n)$, where $g(n)$ is some unknown (presumably simple/nice) function of $n$)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the integrand is $\frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{n!}g(n)e^{-g(n)x}x\;
\mathrm{d}x$ instead of $\frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{n!}g(n)e^{-g(n)x}\;
\mathrm{d}x$? If it was the second case, your problem could be a lot easier.

Comment: You can distribute the integral over the sum to get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^n e^{-\lambda}/[n!\, g(n)]$

Comment: I've added an answer, but something seems fishy about this question. Where does it come from? Is it from a book?

Comment: @Mefitico I'm learning about conditional probability in an undergrad course right now. In a physics paper, I saw an exponential distribution whose parameter was an unknown function g(n) (the paper was experimental physics, they don't make any claims about g(n)). In their context, this exponential distribution is actually a conditional probability: for a given population size N=n, the distribution of population growth steps was exponential with this parameter g(n). This is what led me to the expression above - I wanted to use what I've been learning to see if I could learn anything about g(n)

Comment: (additional info: the population size itself is Poisson distributed, which is where f(n) comes from above)

Answer (score 1):

If as [eyeballfrog](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/395748/eyeballfrog) says, we can switch the integral and the summation:

$$
\int_0^\infty 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{n!}g(n)e^{-g(n)x}x\;
\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{n!}g(n) \int_0^\infty e^{-g(n)x}x\;
\mathrm{d}x  
$$

Now, by comparing both sides of the equation:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{n!}g(n) \int_0^\infty e^{-g(n)x}x\;
\mathrm{d}x  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{n!}g(n)
$$

And assuming both sides need to be identical no matter the value of $\lambda$, then we have for $g(n)\neq 0$:

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-g(n)x}x\;
\mathrm{d}x  = 1
$$

Solving the integral:

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-g(n)x}x\;
\mathrm{d}x  = \left(\frac{1}{g(n)} \right)^2
$$

If the real part of $g(n)$ is greater than 0. Thus the only solution would be $g(n)=1 \, (\forall n)$